# Orthogonal Basis of Zero-Sum Space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, change-of-basis

I would like to find an orthogonal basis of the zero-sum space $\mathcal{V}^{(N)}_0$, defined as the space of all $N$-dimensional real vectors $v$ such that $\sum_i v_i=0$.

That would mean finding a set of $N -1$ vectors that are both orthogonal to each other and orthogonal to $v_0=(1,1,\ldots,1)$.

I tried choosing $v_2=(-1,1,0,\ldots,0),v_3=(-1,0,1,\ldots, 0),\ldots,v_n=(-1,0,0, \ldots, 1)$. These are all orthogonal to $v_0$,  but not to each other, because for instance $\langle v_2,v_3\rangle=1$.

Answer (score 3):

You can just apply the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to your basis to force it to be orthogonal. Alternatively, a variation on your basis would be  $v_n=(\underbrace{1,\ldots, 1}_{n-1} ,1-n,0, \ldots, 0)$, so $v_2=(1,-1,0,\ldots, 0)$, $v_3=(1,1,-2,0,\ldots, 0)$ and so on. This basis is orthogonal by virtue of the fact that for $i\neq j$, $(v_i,v_j)$ is the sum of components of $v_{\min(i,j)}$ which is always $0$.

Comment: Thank you. I do wonder if there is a simpler choice..

Answer (score 2):

Applying Gram-Schmidt will give you ugly vectors that look arbitrary. If you are OK with an answer over $\mathbb C^n$, you may take the $n-1$ vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1} \in \mathbb C^n$ whose $j$-th coordinate is given by:

$$
v_k(j) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot e^{2\pi i \cdot\frac{k\cdot j}{n}}
$$

These vectors form an orthonormal basis of the subspace of $\mathbb C^n$ containing the vectors whose entries sum to zero. They are $n-1$ out of $n$ vectors giving the Fourier basis over the group $\mathbb Z_{n}$. We are only missing $v_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}(1, \dots, 1)$, which spans the 1-dimensional subspace of constant vectors.

All the entries of $v_k$ have the same amplitude. You may check that they sum to zero: each coordinate is $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ times a vertex of the $n$-gon inscribed in the complex unit circle, so they cancel each out by symmetry. Furthermore, $\langle v_i, v_\ell \rangle = 0$ if $i \neq \ell$, which is not as obvious, but also follows by symmetry.

I think this qualifies as a natural choice, it is the most natural choice I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Gram-Schmidt to your choice of vectors to obtain the orthogonal basis.